# PyCharm - "unresolved attribute reference" for super class members

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

This code runs perfectly fine, still PyCharm is unable to resolve attributes of `Timer` super class. Why?
Python 3.6 interpreter is set.

```
from threading import Timer, Event

class TestStatsCollector(Timer):
    def __init__(self, func, interval=60):
        super().__init__(interval, func)

    def run(self):
        while not self.finished.is_set():
            self.finished.wait(self.interval)
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```

Comment: Is this Python 2?

Comment: @user2357112 Python3.6

Comment: is the finished and function properties that pycharm is complaining about?

Comment: @tazer84 yes, actually all variables here are members of Timer super class

Comment: The attributes you're trying to use are undocumented, and they're not in the [stub file](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/threading.pyi) for `threading`. I would guess that the error you're seeing is because you're using attributes that aren't in the stubs.

Comment: (You really shouldn't be using undocumented attributes, even if they don't have a leading underscore. You can just make your own `Thread` subclass instead of subclassing `Timer`.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica As of 2019, the attributes are in the stub file.

Comment: @pstatix: I took another look at the stub file, and I don't see the attributes there.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica [here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/3bd5471744850e1126d15854e6775f10e01d6e12/stdlib/2and3/threading.pyi#L162) you go, they are defined in `__init__` for the `Timer` class.

Comment: @pstatix: No they're not. There's a `function` argument, but no `function` attribute, and `finished` doesn't show up in the file at all.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica But it does show up in the source of `threading.py`, and a type for argument is defined in the stub; together that makes them a valid attribute to use. The stub does not define whether or not an inherited attribute can be used.

Comment: @pstatix: The stub file doesn't have any affect on what you can do at all. If all you care about is what runs, then none of this matters. On the other hand, if you care about static checks, then the stub file matters, and the `function` argument for `__init__` in the stub file has no connection to any attributes. In any case, your initial claim that the attributes are in the stub file is not substantiated by the actual contents of the stub file.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica To whit, your claim about not using attributes that are not defined in the stub file is therefore also not substantiated because they have no affect on the run of the system (or whether or not they are resolved; stubs are for checking type not for inheritance resolution).

Comment: @pstatix: I said "I would guess that the error you're seeing is because you're using attributes that aren't in the stubs." The error the question is about is a Pycharm error from Pycharm's static analysis, not a runtime error. Even if stub files have no affect on runtime behavior, they do affect static analysis.